# Refresh USB port / restart usb service

Tags: usb, catalina

after the upgrade to Catalina I have some problem with the USB hubs. I have three USB hubs (all working fine before the upgrade) that when plugged they are recognised once every 10/15 times. If I plug the usb hub and then restart my Macbook (12", USB C port only) they are working fine. 
I can't keep logging out or restarting each time I need to connect one, and I have already tried to restore my Mac without using any backup (huge waste of time, really ). So I am looking for a way to kill/restart the USB service manually via terminal. The hubs are HDMI, Ethernet and USB hubs, each feature works fine without issue, just the USB doesn't work until restart.
There's no driver or anything to install as they always have been plug and play. I know that Catalina has removed any support to 32bit application but again, there's no software that was needed. It's not a matter of kext because as I said if I restart my Mac everything is working fine.

Anyone aware of how to kill restart the usb kext/process?

ps: Reset Pram didn't help :(

Thank you very much

Comment: I love the MacBook One and fear the answer is going to be the SMC controls this, not the os. I have to disconnect and reconnect on my setup. It’s always been the peripherals that fail and cause me to reconnect so my Mac works for weeks with good gear. Sorry this isn’t a proper answer yet. If I get some logs to prove this, I’ll answer.

Comment: @bmike but when it does happen to you, do you need simply to disconnect the usb accessory and reconnect? That is not enough for me, even if I do that my Mac doesn't recognise it

Comment: Yes - it always works with a disconnect, wait 20 seconds, reconnect. In a few cases, my LG display needs a power cycle, but the mac does the charge sound so I chalk that one rare failure up to the display power control - not the USB bus. I also have two MacBook One (work and home) so they both match this experience.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion? If I logout or reboot the device works fine